# Kattis Problem 'Mali'

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I wrote a solution to the [Mali problem on Kattis](https://open.kattis.com/problems/mali):

> Given inputs *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, *a*<sub>3</sub>, …, *a<sub>n</sub>* and *b*<sub>1</sub>, *b*<sub>2</sub>, *b*<sub>3</sub>, …, *b<sub>n</sub>*, determine *n* pairings (*a<sub>i</sub>*, *b<sub>j</sub>*) such that each number in the *A* sequence is used in exactly one pairing, each number in the *B* sequence is used in exactly one pairing, and the maximum of all sums *a<sub>i</sub>* + *b<sub>j</sub>* is minimal.
>
> #### Input
>
> The first line of input contains a single integer *N* (1 ≤ *N* ≤ 100000), the number of rounds.
>
> The next *N* lines contain two integers *A* and *B* (1 ≤ *A*, *B* ≤ 100), the numbers given in that round.
>
> #### Output
>
> The output consists of *N* lines, one for each round.  Each line should contain the smallest maximal sum for that round.

I'm fairly sure I can get the right answer 100% of the time, but the code exceeds the time limit of one second. I was wondering if you could help me optimize my code to help it run in time, or if you could explain why my code is inefficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int x, c = 0, big = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::vector<int> as, bs;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        bool founda = false, foundb = false;
        int a, b;
        std::cin >> a >> b;
        c++;
        if (c == 1) {
            as.push_back(a);
            bs.push_back(b);
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                if (as[i] < a || i == c-1) {
                    as.insert(as.begin()+i, a);
                    founda = true;
                }
                if (bs[i] < b || i == c-1) {
                    bs.insert(bs.begin()+i, b);
                    foundb = true;
                }
                if (founda == true && foundb == true) 
                    break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            if (as[i] + bs[c-1-i] > big)
                big = as[i] + bs[c-1-i];
        }
        std::cout << big << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: (Programming challenges with "online judges" are carefully crafted with one good solution in mind that can be coded in, say, one hour. Problem parameters (*size*) are chosen such that asymptotically inferior approaches don't complete within the time limit. The implementation platform (language) is figured in: you need to find a solution that re-uses information "between sums/pairs".)

Comment: (For lack of code comments, I didn't try to understand your approach upfront. Integrating input and both preparatory sorts is thinking out-of-the-box!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing all of the *A* and *B* inputs in sorted vectors, basically doing an insertion sort.  A few observations (two minor, one major):

1. The `if (c == 1)` special case should be eliminated.
2. Flag variables (`founda` and `foundb`) suck.  You would be better off writing two separate `for` loops.
3. Each time you insert a value, all values beyond the insertion point need to be shifted over to make room for the insertion.  That means that constructing `as` and `bs` takes O(*N*<sup>2</sup>) time altogether — which is unacceptable, since *N* can be very large.

   However, there are only 100 possible values of *A* and *B*.  So, do a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) instead, building a histogram with 100 buckets.  That would be a much more efficient way to represent the same information, using O(*N*) time and a fixed amount of space.

Comment: Usually a stickler for detail, I commend giving neither more nor less than the principle of (the crucial part of) a good solution.